# Three.js - any problems with cloning a clone?

Tags: three.js

I want to clone objects in quite a complex hierarchy and give each a unique xyz to assemble an even more complex hierarchy. It would be simpler to clone the last clone instance rather than pick out the originally cloned object. Recursion is handled by separate Javascript. Any foreseeable  problems here?

Answer (score 0):

No problem, matrices. Pseudo-code

```
<code>
    srcRootObj.updateMatrixWorld(true);
    for(var i = 0; i < srcRootObj.childrens.lenght; i++) 
    {
        var obj = srcRootObj.childrens[i];
        var m = obj.matrixWorld.clone(); // or matrix
        m.applyYouTransform();
        //dst[i].applyMatrix(m); // this d`t correct
        dst[i].matrix.copy(m);
        // & add recursive if needed
    }
</code>
```

Simply. Why does not approach?

Comment: OK perhaps the question is not clear. I just want to know if having cloned an Object3D can I then clone the clone or should I clone the original? Thanks